# Installing Matlab 2009a in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I have a Matlab 2009a folder(with setup.exe) on Unbuntu 11.04. How can I install matlab on Ubuntu?

Comment: If you have a valid Matlab license, you should be able to download the linux version of Matlab from their homepage.

Answer (score 3):

A file ending with '.exe' is aimed for the Windows operating system. It will never run natively on any flavor of Linux. You need to get the Linux binaries of MATLAB.

Your may check [System Requirements - Release 2011b](http://www.mathworks.ch/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html) for further information. Apart from the Solaris support, there hasn't been much change since 2009a.